# mysql DBvisualizer cannot show link between tables in schema diagram

Tags: mysql

HI guys:

I am using DBvisualizer to manager Mediawiki mysql database. But i try to view schema diagram from DBvisualizer reference tab. But the graph displays no arcs between tables.

I have checked FAQ. it said:

> The graph displays no arcs between tables if the database do no support primary/foreign key mapping or if mappings has not been defined.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any solution for this?

Sure.  Add foreign keys to the appropriate tables, as it sounds like they're missing.

> Mediawiki mysql database

You might want to review [Mediawiki's own page on their database layout](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aDatabase_layout), which happens to include a pretty graph with the arrows you're expecting.

Judging from the table descriptions on the sub-pages, it looks like Mediawiki does not enforce foreign keys at the database level.

Comment: thx for your reply. One more question. if mediawiki does not enforce foreign keys at the database level. How can it link between the tables?

Comment: @user380690: If by "it" you mean Mediawiki, then the relationships are possible to maintain at the software level.  If by "it" you mean the software that generated the diagram, then it's likely that they altered the schema to use foreign keys for that one specific instance.